# What does /etc/ssh.cache mean to docker-sshd?

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm attempting to understand the following shell script:
https://github.com/macropin/docker-sshd/blob/master/entry.sh

Specifically this part:

```
# Copy default config from cache
if [ ! "$(ls -A /etc/ssh)" ]; then
   cp -a /etc/ssh.cache/* /etc/ssh/
fi
```

This is the first time I've seen `ssh.cache` mentioned.  I just want to verify that this is a default configuration that has been baked into the image by the Dockerfile author and not something that is a component of OpenSSH?

TIA,
Ole

Comment: ...so, edit your question to be a fit for the answer (posed about what the code means, rather than what the directory name means), and I'll vote to reopen. (Not that "what does code X mean?" is generally a very useful class of question, but it's not explicitly off-topic either).

Comment: I've tried to edit a bit further. It looks good to me now, and I've filed a vote to reopen; like the vote to close, it'll require four other folks to agree. BTW, you might find http://explainshell.com/ to be of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about that directory.  It's just a directory that script is using to hold a default set of ssh configs, and then copy them into /etc/ssh when the container starts up.